# Unable to use the Symfony installer because of an https error

Tags: php, https, openssl, symfony-3.1, uwamp

I am trying to learn Symfony ... started reading tutorials and it seems that the best way to get started is to use the build in Symfony installer. So I installed uwamp on my USB key drive. It seems to be working fine cause the test page opens up when I navigate to localhost.

PHP version is set to 7.0.3 and when I open the windows console and type php -v the right version is selected so I have the global path set right.

I have checked all the PHP and Apache modules and made sure I had all the required stuff unable including OpenSSL and curl as well as all the other recommended stuff. Actually, all of them were already pre-configured with the uwamp installation (thanks for that)

So when I try to use the Symfony command this is what I get:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when y
ou configured PHP?
[file] phar://J:/UwAmp/www/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
[line] 406
[message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
[file] phar://J:/UwAmp/www/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
[line] 406
[message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
[file] phar://J:/UwAmp/www/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
[line] 407
```

I don't get it ... I do have OpenSSL set right ... what else do I need to do? I even checked manually the ini files and made sure the semicolumn was removed.

Comment: can you try running `composer.phar diag`?

Comment: J:\UwAmp\www>php composer.phar diag
    Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: you do have composer.phar in `J:\UwAmp\www` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of digging around I finally found how to solve my problem.

1. Make sure openssl is enabled using the GUI
2. Find uwamp-directory/php/php-x.x.x/php_uwamp.ini
3. Copy the content into a new file named php.ini in the same directory
4. Replace extension_dir and zend_extension with full paths instead of {} vars

in my case:

```
extension_dir = "J:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-7.0.3\ext"
zend_extension = "J:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-7.0.3\zend_ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

From what I understand, the Windows CLI does not use the php_uwamp.ini file and there for uses default values. Creating a file named php.ini with the corrected extension paths will make it work.